# Shadow on curved image view on toolbar

Tags: android, xml, material-design, elevation

I have a bottom `toolbar` that has a fab like button in the center.

[image: toolbar]

I am trying to add shadow to this bar. It consists of :

- Parent `RelativeLayout`
- `RelativeLayout` with 4 image views.
- `ImageView` centered in the toolbar(the circle button)

I want to add shadow effect to this toolbar. If I elevate the bottom bar then it hides the `ImageView` that is not included in the `RelativeLayout`.
If I also elevate that `ImageView` I get a Circular shadow effect like below on that `ImagView`. I only want the top curved portion of the icon to have a shadow effect.
[image]